# Set language to each project in Multi-root Workspaces Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working in multi-root-workspace VSCode has project with different languages.

```
root-folder/
   file.code-workspace
   project-in-java/
   project-in-python/
   project-in-angular/
   project-in-react/
```

When multi-roor-workspace has been opended, is there any way to setting start up project on each languages?, example: maven build only maven projects, gradle build only gradle projects, python build/refresh only python projects etc...

Note: I don't have problem with launch.json, this has been handled successfully in `file.code-workspace`

How can I set language type to each project in file.code-workspace?
Are there any better practices or configurtions for this on multi workspaces in visual-studio-code?

Comment: you don't set it per workspace, the file extensions determine the type. You set a particular launch config per workspace, that is different for each language, see VSC debugging doc

Comment: I refreshed my post. I don't have problem with launch settings however some information on start up workspace to  refresh/build each project and their languages.

Comment: I guess just like in Make,CMake files, specify/hard code the directories in the specific configuration files at the root-folder level, create tasks to run maven and gradle with a master config file, or create shell scripts that call maven and gradle in the hard coded directories, VSC is an editor not an IDE that supports some tools, maybe somebody has written an extension to help you with